# Is that thread safe to cache objects in static list

Tags: java

We have lot of configuration files which are loaded when web application starts.

These configuration files are parsed into java beans, and we store them in a static List.

all these information are only for read at runtime.

Currently I just use a ArrayList to do this.

Is that ok ?

Comment: Why can't you use synchronised list instead of plain array list? When in doubt, don't.

Comment: As long as the information are stored for read only purpose, I don't see a problem in making that as a static

Comment: @KDM why would you use a synchronized list, when what you want is an immutable list of immutable beans?

Comment: @DavidConrad you are right. `Collections.unmodifiableList` is the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the configuration is loaded when the application starts and is only for read at runtime, I would wrap the list with [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) and make the beans immutable. Then you don't need to worry about not exposing the list.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure:

- You never expose the list as `public`
- You don't return the list from a method
- Just provide the getter methods to get a value from the list
- Don't provide the methods to change/add/delete a value from the list

Hope that should do.

Comment: I would wrap the list with `Collections.unmodifiableList` and make the beans immutable. Then you don't need to worry about not exposing the list.

Comment: @DavidConrad please make your comment as an answer, and I will take it.